# Некорректное отображение 3d объектов three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Во время вращения 2 кубов, вложенных один в другой, на пересечении полигонов внешнего куба образуются зазоры. Можно ли это исправить программными средствами three.js или здесь нужно юзать левые средства?

[image: 1 скриншот]

[image: 2 скриншот]

[image: 3 скриншот]

Сам код:

```
    <script>
        var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var cube, group;

        var targetRotationX = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDownX = 0;

        var targetRotationY = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDownY = 0;

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

        var mouseY = 0;
        var mouseYOnMouseDown = 0;

        var windowHalfX = 500;
        var windowHalfY = 500;

        group = new THREE.Group();

        init();
        animate();

        //Инициализация рабочей области
        function init()
        {
            //Инициализация контейнера
            container = document.getElementById('container');

            //Камера
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, 1, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 100;

            //Сцена
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //Внутренний куб
            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20,20,20);
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 0.5}));
            group.add(cube);

            //Внешний куб
            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(22,22,22);
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, opacity: 0.7}));
            group.add(cube);

            //Вывод созданных элементов на сцену
            scene.add(group);

            //Создание рендерера
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
            renderer.setSize(1000, 1000);
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            //События мыши для вращения кубов
            container.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
            container.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
            container.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

            //Событие изменения размера окна
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            console.log(scene)      

        }

        function onWindowResize()
        {
            windowHalfX = 500;
            windowHalfY = 500;
            camera.aspect = 1;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( 1000, 1000);
        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            container.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
            container.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
            container.addEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;
            mouseYOnMouseDown = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
            targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;
        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event)
        {
            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
            targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
            targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp(event)
        {
            container.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
            container.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
            container.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
        }

        function onDocumentMouseOut(event)
        {
            container.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
            container.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
            container.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart(event)
        {
            if (event.touches.length == 1)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;
                mouseYOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;        
            }
        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove(event)
        {
            if (event.touches.length == 1)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.05;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.05;
            }
        }

        function animate()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }

        function render()
        {   
            group.rotation.y += (targetRotationX - group.rotation.y) * 0.1;
            group.rotation.x += (targetRotationY - group.rotation.x) * 0.05;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Это артефакты CanvasRenderer. Есть ли у вас возможность использовать WebGLRenderer?

Comment: Есть, конечно, однако не каждый браузер его поддерживает.

Comment: Обычно в таких ситуациях советуют применять опцию `overdraw` на материал, но я смотрю, что она не помогает при вложенных элементах: `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff, overdraw: 0.5 })`

Comment: Я бы советовал все-таки использовать WebGLRenderer, и проверять поддерживается ли он у пользователя. Если нет - включать CanvasRenderer  - все же лучше чем ничего.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо.